# After running bundle install, it instantiates the wrong version of a gem, rendering an error

Tags: rubygems, rake, bundle, bundler

I have tried using bundle update, and it returns successful, bundle install responds that it was successful as well. Yet when I try to run db:migrate, it returns an error, saying a couple different gems are running the wrong version.

I know that I could delete the other versions of the gems to let it run, but I am curious if there is a way to avoid the problem/and curious why the problem why it is not working.

The gems that I've had this happen with are sqlite3 and rake, as well as a couple others.

Comment: We need more information as this could be due to a number of issues.

Comment: what info do you need ?

Comment: rake task, bundle output, error output, etc.

Comment: i fixed the problem by simply uninstalling and reinstalling the gems! Thanks for trying to help